# Ls \ gives me a new prompt what is this for?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, zsh

Ls \ changes my shell prompt from $ to >. If I put in any text I get an error and it returns me to $.

Does this have any type of function that I could use?

Or is it an effect of the backslash which is cancelled out by any sort of input on an unsupported command?

The code was executed on an lxde terminal in lubuntu in case that's relevant.

Comment: Questions about using your shell as a user, as opposed to writing software with it, belong at [unix.se] or [Super User](https://superuser.com/). Stack Overflow is only for questions about problems specific to software development.

Comment: That said, a backslash at the end of a line is a _line continuation_. That means that anything you type is considered part of the same command as your prior line.

Answer (score 0):

When the backslash character is placed at the end of a line it indicates that the bash command continues onto the next line. The '>' character is letting you know that the terminal is waiting for the second part of the command.

If on that next line you enter '.' and then enter you will get the listing of the files in your current directory. You're likely getting an error because the text you submit on the new line is not a valid directory.

Source: https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169504&seqNum=10

Comment: Questions that are off-topic should be closed, not answered. See the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).